# is there an example how can I use Threejs Frustum

Tags: three.js

I saw some examples in stack overlow. but they are already very old [Frustum](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum)

I searched a lot but, I couldn't find anything.

I have a plane including 10000 + stands. I need to render only some stands which in camera vision area

Answer (score 0):

found solution with updated version.

```js
 camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / -1, width / 1, height / 1, height / -1, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 4;
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    if (featureFlags.cameraHelper) {
        const helper = new THREE.CameraHelper(camera);
        scene.add(helper);
    }

    // every time the camera or objects change position (or every frame)

    camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure the camera matrix is updated
    camera.matrixWorldInverse.copy(camera.matrixWorld).invert();
    cameraViewProjectionMatrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);
    frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(cameraViewProjectionMatrix);
```

```js
function render() {
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    camera.matrixWorldInverse.copy(camera.matrixWorld).invert();
    cameraViewProjectionMatrix.multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);
    frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(cameraViewProjectionMatrix);

    const visibleObjects = [];

    scene.traverse((object) => {
        if (object?.isMesh) {
            object.geometry.computeBoundingBox();

            if (frustum.intersectsObject(object)) {
                visibleObjects.push(object);
            }
        }
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```